# deploying servlet on web server

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I am developing Android Application for weather forecast.currently i've written server side code in servlet.
My webserver is Apache Tomcat. How can I deploy my servlet on webserver? what are the steps for deploying servlet.Thank you in advance.

```
package com.example.WeatherDetails;
import com.example.Info.INFORMATION;
import com.example.Info.WeatherInformation;
import java.io.IOException;    
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;    
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;    
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;    
import com.google.gson.Gson;    
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;      
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;    
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;    
public class WeatherDetails extends HttpServlet        
{    
 public WeatherDetails()     

{
  super();

 }

 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException     
 {

 doPost(request,response);

 }

 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
 throws ServletException, IOException {

 String LAT = request.getParameter("LAT");

 String LONGITUDE = request.getParameter("LONGITUDE");

  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

  //get list of countries

  WeatherInformation WeatherInformation = new WeatherInformation();

  ArrayList<INFORMATION> WeatherInfo = WeatherInformation.getList(LAT,LONGITUDE);

  Gson gson = new Gson();

  JsonArray arrayObj=new JsonArray();

  for(int i=0;i<WeatherInfo.size();i++)

{

   INFORMATION information = WeatherInfo.get(i);

   JsonElement productObj = gson.toJsonTree(information); 

   arrayObj.add(productObj);

  }


  //create a new JSON object

  JsonObject myObj = new JsonObject();

  //add property as success

  myObj.addProperty("success", true);

  //add the countryList object

  myObj.add("WeatherInfo", arrayObj);

  //convert the JSON to string and send back

  out.println(myObj.toString());

  out.close();    

 }        

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you will have to provide servlet mapping in web.xml file

as

```
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>servletname</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>packagename.classname</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>servletname</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/servletname</url-pattern>
```

// this is the servlet root using which u will access your servlet

after this deploy it on server and execute on localhost using url : `localhost:8080/projectname/servletroot`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i want to deploy it on webserver. On the localhost it works perfectly fine.